# Find and append to files in Unix

Tags: shell, unix, find

I am trying to find files by filename and write to them.

```
find ./ -name "filename" -type f -exec echo "some string" >> {} \;
```

This creates a file named `{}` and writes the string to it for every match instead of writing to the files found.

Comment: what's the error you are getting..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
... -exec sed '$asome string' -i {} \;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can spawn a subshell as part of the `-exec` and then use redirection as usual:

```
find . -name "filename" -type f -exec bash -c 'echo "some string" >> "$1"' _ {} \;
```

`_` is a dummy handle for `$0` within `bash -c`.